# How to use references/pointers with mathematical operations in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ pointers and references. Say I have two variables i1 and i2, is there a way I can track their difference (or any other operation), even if one of them changes. My attempt at this is shown below, as well as what I want to achieve.

```cpp
int i1 = 20;
int i2 = 20;
int*r1 = &i1;
int*r2 = &i2;
int s  = *r1-*r2;
std::cout << s << std::endl;
i1 = 40;
std::cout << s << std::endl;
//OUTPUT
//0 <- 20-20
//0 <- How do I make this 20, since 40-20 is 20
```

Comment: s is already calculated.  It won't change now just because one of the source variable's value changed.

Comment: So is this not possible in any language. Well, that's a bummer, guess I will find a workaround. But I will keep this post around anyways, for any insight.

Comment: There are a few languages that directly do what you want, but they are rare.

Comment: It can work if `s` is "a thing that mostly behaves like an `int` but auto-updates", which is close enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is not doable, as you can't take a reference to an expression. Once you have saved the result of the expression `*r1 - *r2` into your `s` variable, you would have to perform the `*r1 - *r2` expression again after updating the source values to save a new result into `s`, eg:

```
int  i1 = 20;
int  i2 = 20;
int *r1 = &i1;
int *r2 = &i2;
int  s  = *r1 - *r2;
std::cout << s << std::endl;
i1 = 40;
s = *r1 - *r2; // <-- ADD THIS!
std::cout << s << std::endl;
//OUTPUT
//0 <- 20-20
//20 <- 40-20
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/DQ0RfJ)

For what you are attempting, you might consider using use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead, let it capture references to the original variables, and then you can invoke the lambda when needed so it can calculate a new result each time, eg:

```
int i1 = 20;
int i2 = 20;
auto s = [&]{ return i1 - i2; };
std::cout << s() << std::endl;
i1 = 40;
std::cout << s() << std::endl;
//OUTPUT
//0 <- 20-20
//20 <- 40-20
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/5XIW9i)

Comment: Without knowing why they wanted this behavior, it's hard to be sure how useful this really is.  The lambda is still just recalculating, it's just hiding it behind a function call.

Comment: If you're going to bother with a lambda, why not replace it with a full functor that has `operator int()`? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9446ce448ce3c967

Answer (score 2):

You use functions for this purpose, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i1 = 20;
    int i2 = 20;
    auto s = [&i1, &i2] { return i1 - i2; };

    std::cout << s() << std::endl;
    i1 = 40;
    std::cout << s() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau a lambda function is a function  (a class member function with nicer syntax)

Comment: A lambda is not a function, it is a functor (a class type with an overloaded `operator()`), which can act *like* a function in some contexts.  But an actual function itself is a distinct language construct of its own. Don't mix up terminology, you are just going to confuse people.